# Get table names from database, which contains particular data type column

Tags: sql, database, sqldatatypes

I want to get all the `Table Names` from database which Table has a Column with `particular DataType`.

Let's say image is the `DataType`, then I want to find all the Table Names which have one or more column of image type in it.

Comment: information_schema.columns can be used.

Comment: But How to use it??.. can you please post a answer?

Comment: "select * from information_schema.columns". Add where DATA_TYPE = 'datatype' to get columns of a specific type. (This is ANSI/ISO SQL standard, not supported by all dbms products.)

Comment: @jarlh Yessss It work's... Thanks a lott.. Please post a answer .. I'll mark it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from information_schema.columns
```

Add `where DATA_TYPE = 'datatype'` to get columns of a specific type.

(This is ANSI/ISO SQL standard, not supported by all dbms products.)